# What could went wrong if the "cloud messages" data are not exported from Firebase to BigQuery anymore?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

Cloud messages (push notices) sent with Firebase to my app users **was exported to BigQuery** - so I can get stats about that. It was loaded in firebase_messaging table on BigQuery.
In short - **it was working for few months and now it stopped** since last week.

I have checked:

- Integrations section in Firebase console - BigQuery is still linked with my apps.
- If apps was updated before sync stopped - no, there was no changes.
- If anything changed in push notification structure (sent from backend) - no, the same for all notifications since few weeks
- Limits are not exceeded

Comment: Hi.We're experiencing the same problem since November 9th 2020

Checked integrations and quotas, both are fine.

Comment: Did you try to reset export in Integrations section?

Comment: I emailed BQ supprt and they fixed it for me issue, I'm on free plan. Just email the support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Despite the fact that it is a free plan - it somehow requires an assigned credit card (e.g.)

Comment: Where should we assign credit card - in Firebase or in GCP?